# JSON Associative array mapped using Spring MVC support

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

If I have a JSON array like so:

```
{
"type": "anAction", 
"fired": "2011-09-16 20:00:00", 
"data[id]": "1234", 
"data[list_id]": "7890",
"data[email]": "abc@xxx.com",
"data[email][foo]": "blah"    
}
```

Does someone know how I can use Spring's jacksonMessageConverter and maybe a custom ObjectMapper to convert those associative JSON arrays into Java objects?

I'm using @RequestBody annotation for receiving the JSON string.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is valid JSON

Comment: data needs to be a nested object by itself - `"data": {"id":"1234",`

Comment: The JSON is perfectly valid. Try this JSON parser: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it will happily accept and format it.

Comment: The JSON is valid but "data" is not considered as an array. Try to parse it in javascript. It will create an object with 6 properties.